# Javascript array index

Tags: javascript

Sorry for asking a noob question but if I have an array:

```
MyArray["2cd"]="blah1";
MyArray["3cx"]="blah3";
MyArray["8cz"]="blah2";
```

And a string `myStr="2cd";`
And then I use MyArray[myStr] to get the value of blah, how can I get the number I am accessing in the object/array or 0 in this case?

Comment: An index is a number. You can access MyArray[0] or MyArray[cd] if cd is a number or you need parseInt("2cd", 10) and that'll return 2 so might as well do MyArray[2].

Comment: An "index" is a numeric string (e.g. "0", "1", "2"). For the OP, javascript arrays are just plain objects with a special length property and methods inherited from Array.prototype. So you can use an array just like an object (not liked but works just fine). Many array methods are generic and can be used on plain objects with suitable properties.

Comment: I've created a jsfiddle demo from the example you gave: http://jsfiddle.net/zxZTX/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I may read between the lines, it sounds like you're thinking that the code you posted:

```
MyArray["2cd"] = "blah1";
MyArray["3cx"] = "blah3";
MyArray["8cz"] = "blah2";
```

will automatically become the equivalent of:

```
MyArray[0] = MyArray["2cd"] = "blah1";
MyArray[1] = MyArray["3cx"] = "blah3";
MyArray[2] = MyArray["8cz"] = "blah2";
```

and therefore you can get the string `"blah1"` either of these two ways:

```
var foo = MyArray[0];  // sets foo to "blah1"
var bar = MyArray["2cd"]  // also sets bar to "blah1"
```

But that's not how JavaScript works.

You certainly *can* set things up so you can use my `MyArray[0]` and `MyArray["2cd"]` to fetch the same value, but you have to do it explicitly as in my example.

One thing you didn't mention is how you declared `MyArray` itself. Is it an `Array` or an `Object`? That is, before the code you posted, did you create `MyArray` with:

```
var MyArray = {};  // or equivalently, var Array = new Object;
```

or:

```
var MyArray = [];  // or equivalently, var Array = new Array;
```

The first example creates an `Object`, the second an `Array`.

What is a bit confusing is that JavaScript has both of these two types, which in many cases you can use somewhat interchangeably. But it's customary to use an `Object` when you are using arbitrary (generally but not necessarily non-numeric) keys into the object, as in your example. Conversely, it's customary to use an `Array` when you are primarily using strictly numeric indexes.

In fact, JavaScript's `Array` type *inherits* from the `Object` type. An `Array` is simply an `Object` with some additional behavior:

- An `Array` has additional methods such as `.push()` which appends an item to the array.
- An `Array` has a `.length` property which is automatically updated when you add elements with `.push()` or a direct `array[123]` assignment, or when you remove elements with `.pop()` or other methods.

What JavaScript doesn't have, as Fabrício pointed out, is an "associative array" that behaves like what you might find in some other languages. It has Objects and it has Arrays (which inherit from Objects), and you have to deal with each of those on their own terms.

Comment: You could start by making it clear that there are no associative arrays in JS.

Comment: Definitely! Thanks for mentioning that. I had posted my original reply from my phone while waiting for my daughter at the mall, so it was a bit terse. Now that I have a keyboard handy, I elaborated on arrays vs. objects a bit.